# List of killed apps

Tags: process, logs, kill

Is there a command to list latest killed processes?

Or to search through log file for killed app, for example called "my_app"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your program was being managed by systemd, upstart, cron, or something similar, there should be a relevant log for death of the process somewhere in /var/log (the precise log file depends on the distro you're using and the system which manages the process).

If the process was killed by the kernel due to something like an OOM, there will be a log entry in the kernel log indicating as such (often found in `/var/log/kern.log`).

Otherwise, by default there is no sort of logging for random processes being killed. You can setup **[process accounting](http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-monitor-user-activity-with-psacct-or-acct-tools/)** and use `lastcomm` to see a history of executed commands. By evaluating `lastcomm`'s output you can determine if an arbitrary process was killed using `SIGTERM`.

Example of `lastcomm` output when process accounting is enabled:

```
$ yes >/dev/null &
[1] 24350

$ pkill yes
[1]  + terminated  yes > /dev/null

$ lastcomm | grep yes
yes                  X alienth  pts/11     3.45 secs Wed Sep 16 00:55
```

The `X` in lastcomm's output denotes that the process was terminated with a `SIGTERM` signal (which is the signal used by `kill` by default).